# Правописание наречий

Tags: орфография, наречия

Почему "взамен" пишется слитно, понятно, но почему "в замену" — раздельно? Никак не могу подобрать правило для этого случая, более того, даже ни разу не слышал такого слова. Как быть?

Comment: Как быть? См. в НКРЯ https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj8qGAoICAEQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHAoaChgKA3JlcRIRCg/QsiDQt9Cw0LzQtdC90YMwAQ==

Answer (score 2):

```
Никак не могу подобрать правило для этого случая, более 
того, даже ни разу не слышал такого слова. Как быть?
```

**Правило нужно?**

1. **[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=69#pp69)** Эти наречия пишутся слитно:  вблизи, вбок, вброд... взамен.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=70#pp70)**  Пункт 3. Пишутся раздельно (в два слова) употребленные в наречном значений сочетания существительных с предлогами: **в:** в дым, в лоск, (пьяный) в стельку, в подбор, в придачу, в складчину, в старину, в стык, в тупик, в тупике; в головах, в ногах;

Сюда же: ***в замену.***

2. **[**ПАС под ред. Лопатина**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=73#pp73)**

§ 139. Во всех остальных (не регламентированных в § 136 — 138) случаях наречия (наречные сочетания) пишутся слитно либо раздельно, причем их написание устанавливается **в словарном порядке.**

**[Взамен](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD&all=x)**  **[В замену](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/8664/%D0%B2)**

**[Примеры в Нацкорпусе](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cm8iLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHAoaChgKA3JlcRIRCg/QsiDQt9Cw0LzQtdC90YMwAA==)**

Comment: Sharon, ссылка на примеры в НКРЯ ведёт не туда.

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено.

Answer (score 1):

```
 — А можно без правил?

 — Да, словарь и грамматика (словообразование и 
  управление падежом). Тогда и правила можно будет 
  объяснить и понять. (Словарь нужен для 
  проверки выбранного решения.)
```

**1. Наречие *"взамен"***

[**ВЗАМЕН.**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD) I. **нареч.** Вместо этого, в обмен. Прислать в. кого-л. другого. Попросить что-л. в. II. **предлог.** чего. Вместо. В. урока русского языка был проведён урок истории. Выдать справку в. диплома.

*Заменить – **взамен**.* Наречие не употребляется без приставки.  Слитное написание **приставки.**

Некоторые наречия со слитным написанием образуются от **отглагольных существительных** с помощью **приставки** и **нулевого суффикса** (иногда они не употребляются  без приставки), например:

*пролететь – напролёт, перекосить – наперекос, разладиться – вразлад, раскачать – враскачку, вытягивать – навытяжку, перехватить – наперехват.*

**2. Наречное выражение "в замену"**

**[В ЗАМЕНУ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/8664/%D0%B2)**

В словаре есть существительное ***"замена".***

**[**ЗАМЕНА,**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)** -ы; ж. 1. к Заменить - заменять. З. одного слова другим. 2. Тот, кто (то, что) заменяет кого-, что-л. Найти замену для кого-л.

***В замену,*** предлог ***В***, наречное выражение  (обстоятельственное существительное), **предложное управление В.п.**, значение **направленности** (для чего, с какой целью) — **чтобы заменить.**  Раздельное написание **предлога.**

*Просить что-то **в замену,** взять кого-то **в замену,** предложить (что-то) **в замену**.*

**Пример:**  **[Нацкорпус](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cm8iLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHAoaChgKA3JlcRIRCg/QsiDQt9Cw0LzQtdC90YMwAA==)**

*Она, правда, надеялась найти кого-нибудь **себе в замену**, но никто ей не попадался.* Людмила Петрушевская, 2003.